# Make the toolbar of TeXnicCenter 2.02 French

Tags: texniccenter

I use TeXnicCenter Version 2.02. and I like to make the toolbar French. So I just need a `TxcResFrench.dll` file to put in the language folder (`c:\program files\TeXnicCenter\language`). So, I did search on the net the French dictionary which contains this file, but I have not found it. Can someone direct me?

Answer (score 3):

*I fear the only answer is:*

There is no `TxcResFrench.dll`, and also no `TxcResFrancais.dll` or `TxcResFrançais.dll` for version 2.02. <sup><sub>The German language file is not named  `TxcResGerman.dll`, but `TxcResDeutsch.dll`.</sub></sup>

I only found a hint that there existed a French language file for version 1.0 RC1: [TxcResFrench.dll Details. Is this file safe?](http://www.isthisfilesafe.com/sha1/97EAEA75B93EAC08C66397548FA8E17A9F2C220E_details.aspx).

You could make a feature request in the user forum on LaTeX-Community.org ([Feature Suggestions](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewforum.php?f=36)) or according to [TeXnicCenter » Support](http://www.texniccenter.org/support/) better in the developers area: [Suggest a feature](http://sourceforge.net/p/texniccenter/user-reports/new/) (Attention, direct link to open a new ticket!).

Comment: I have already the dictionary `version RC1`, I tried his file `TxcResFrancais.dll` , it is not compatible with `version 2.02`. thank you for your help.